# Rolling units processed and backlog with capacity constraints

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have a problem that has me thoroughly stumped. Hoping there's a nice way to solve this that I can't think of. A similar problem can be written as follows:

There is a station that is given new units to process daily. It has a maximum capacity of units it can process every day. I'm looking to write a query to get the backlogged units as well as daily units processed. Something like this - would like to have a query that turns this input into the following output:

```
WITH INPUT AS (
SELECT 1 AS DAY, 100 AS NEW_UNITS, 150 AS MAX_CAPACITY UNION ALL
SELECT 2 AS DAY, 300 AS NEW_UNITS, 150 AS MAX_CAPACITY UNION ALL
SELECT 3 AS DAY, 200 AS NEW_UNITS, 150 AS MAX_CAPACITY UNION ALL
SELECT 4 AS DAY, 0 AS NEW_UNITS, 150 AS MAX_CAPACITY UNION ALL
SELECT 5 AS DAY, 200 AS NEW_UNITS, 150 AS MAX_CAPACITY 
),

OUTPUT AS (
SELECT 1 AS DAY, 100 AS NEW_UNITS, 150 AS MAX_CAPACITY, 100 AS PROCESSED, 0 AS BACKLOG UNION ALL
SELECT 2 AS DAY, 300 AS NEW_UNITS, 150 AS MAX_CAPACITY, 150 AS PROCESSED, 150 AS BACKLOG UNION ALL
SELECT 3 AS DAY, 200 AS NEW_UNITS, 150 AS MAX_CAPACITY, 150 AS PROCESSED, 200 AS BACKLOG UNION ALL
SELECT 4 AS DAY, 0 AS NEW_UNITS, 150 AS MAX_CAPACITY, 150 AS PROCESSED, 50 AS BACKLOG UNION ALL
SELECT 5 AS DAY, 200 AS NEW_UNITS, 150 AS MAX_CAPACITY, 150 AS PROCESSED, 100 AS BACKLOG 
)

SELECT *
FROM INPUT
```

I hope this makes sense. I am able to write a solution looping through each day but performance is terrible and not scalable at all. Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below is option to try for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
#standardSQL
CREATE TEMP FUNCTION ttt(arr ARRAY<STRUCT<day INT64, units INT64, capacity INT64>>)
RETURNS ARRAY<STRUCT<day INT64, units INT64, capacity INT64, processed INT64, backlog INT64>>
LANGUAGE js AS """
  r = []; backlog = 0;
  for (i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    units = backlog + parseInt(arr[i].units);
    processed = Math.min(units, arr[i].capacity)
    backlog = units - processed;
    r.push(arr[i]);
    r[i].processed = processed;
    r[i].backlog = backlog;
  }
return r;
""";
SELECT line.*
FROM (
  SELECT ttt(array_agg(t ORDER BY day)) arr
  FROM INPUT t
), UNNEST(arr) line
```

if to apply to sample data from your question - output is

[image]

Obviously, above approach has some size related limitations which usually can be addressed by partitioning

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid this solution won't help you since Google BigQuery does not support Recursive CTEs, as far as I know. Google suggests using a `WHILE` loop but it's unclear to me how performant that solution can be.

The solution shown below (for PostgreSQL) may give you some ideas, so I'll leave it here. You can do:

```
with recursive input as (
select 1 as day, 100 as new_units, 150 as max_capacity union all
select 2 as day, 300 as new_units, 150 as max_capacity union all
select 3 as day, 200 as new_units, 150 as max_capacity union all
select 4 as day, 0 as new_units, 150 as max_capacity union all
select 5 as day, 200 as new_units, 150 as max_capacity 
),
d as (
  select *, 
    least(new_units, max_capacity) as processed,
    0 as backlog 
  from input where day = 1
 union all
  select
    i.*,
    least(i.new_units + d.backlog, i.max_capacity),
    i.new_units + d.backlog - least(i.new_units + d.backlog, i.max_capacity)
  from d
  join input i on i.day = d.day + 1
)
select * from d order by day;
```

Result:

```
day  new_units  max_capacity  processed  backlog
---  ---------  ------------  ---------  -------
  1        100           150        100        0
  2        300           150        150      150
  3        200           150        150      200
  4          0           150        150       50
  5        200           150        150      100
```

See running example at [DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/v6QKHGkLKDrLt3Qqx9wu5V/0).

As a general strategy, I don't see a way around processing the rows in order. You need to have/compute the backlog of the previous row in order to compute the current row.

I wonder if you can write a query that computes all rows at the same time. This reminds me of the old "accelerated binary addition" strategy. Maybe it's possible to apply it here.

Comment: question is tagged with `google-bigquery` - not with `postgresql`! anyway - looks like it does not applicable here as BigQuery unfortunately [yet] does not support recursive CTE :o(